# Disable React Input Range Slider from 'react-range-slider'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rangeslider

How to disable InputRange Slider in reactjs using javascript?
I have tried giving an id to it and change the disabled property to true but it didnt work.

```
handleAnimations(animations) {
    document.getElementById("len").disabled = true;
    //some code
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.getElementById("len").disabled = false;
    }, i * ANIMATION_SPEED_MS);
  }
handleChange(val){
    this.setState({arraybarvalue:val});
    this.resetArray();
  }
.
.
.
.
.
   render() {
    const { array } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
          <div  style={{width:100}} className="text-white" >Length<InputRange id="len" disabled={false}  style={{width:50}} step={2} minValue={10} maxValue={210} value={this.state.arraybarvalue} onChange={val => this.setState({ arraybarvalue: val })} onChangeComplete={val=>this.handleChange(val)}></InputRange></div>
      </>
    );
}
```

Comment: does the InputRange Custom Component have an id property that sets the id attribute to the input element inside the component? Because we don't know what InputRange is

Comment: Hey, if you need to change it, you would need to control it via a state, rather than the directly modifying the DOM. React re-renders due to lot of reasons and your change to the DOM would be lost. This is a thumb rule in React.

Comment: InputRange is not a custom component.It is imported from react-range-slider.

Comment: @Panther Is there no other way than changing it through state?